# Ubuntu 20.04 problems with interface after installation

Tags: ubuntu, interface

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa. After the restart, I found a particular problem with the interface (see figure attached).
I'm a beginner in the use of Ubuntu, I have managed to work with it using the tutorials in the community when I need to do or install something from terminal.

I really will appreciate help with this problem.

[image: interface after ubuntu focal fossa installation]Thanks...

Comment: What exactly means "I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04"? Do you mean a fresh installation on an empty disk? Or some kind of update installation? According to the icons I would think that you already used the system for a while. Please [edit] your question to add information. Don't use comments to answer.

Comment: See the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/fuzzy-graphics-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04) to a similar question